# OpenCL eat host memory and device memory the same time

Tags: opencl

My OpenCL program is like this:

1. init_opencl
2. process
3. release_opencl

In **1. init_opencl**, I pre-create all buffers that will be used, like this:

```
g_mem_under_down_lap_pyr_32FC3 = clCreateBuffer(g_ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
        g_sizeMgr->getPyrCapacity() * 3 * sizeof(float), nullptr, &err);
g_mem_mean_down_lap_pyr_32FC3 = clCreateBuffer(g_ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
        g_sizeMgr->getPyrCapacity() * 3 * sizeof(float), nullptr, &err);
```

then in **2. process**, I use **clEnqueueWriteBuffer** to transfer data from host memory to buffer first, then run kernels. At the last, I read out the data from buffer with **clEnqueueReadBuffer**.

In the end in **3. release_opencl**, I call **clReleaseMemObject** to release all the buffers.

But when I run the program, I observed that the in the **2. process**, the host memory and the device memory are increase about 600MB at the same time.

**host memory**

[image: host memory]

**device memory**

[image: device memory]

My question is:

Why does the opencl program occupy host memory with it has occupied device memory?

And how to make may opencl program not occupy host memory?

My test platform is GTX 750.

And in snapdragon 820, I also find the system memory increases 600MB. But in this platform, I don't the GPU memory's change.

Comment: Different OpenCL implementation may vary, the current ones normally store a copy of the memory on host side. This is due to the need to store buffer in an intermediate space when operating with multiple Devices.
Maybe is possible to force it with memory "migration", or with pinned memory.